# Create Cart object once user logs in

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

My app is built so that only authenticated users can purchase items so there is only need for a cart when the use logs in, my script then pulls the cart id that relates to that user  so my API can work its magic.

I cannot get the Cart object to be created. I have tried many attempts and this is my latest:

ef user_login(request):

```
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
        
        try:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(user=user)
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            cart = Cart.objects.create(user=user)
        request.session['cart_id'] = cart.id

        messages.success(request, ("You were successfully logged in..."))
    else:
        messages.success(request, ("There was an error logging in, please try again..."))
        return redirect('home')
   
return render(request, 'authenticate/login.html', {})
```